# Exclude local WEB-INF/lib jars from packaged war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have mentioned the dependency for all the required JAR's in the pom.xml. Now, Since the dependencies are defined in **POM**, the JAR's will be automatically packed in the lib folder.

I want to exclude all the JAR's in the lib,present in the project source.
The Dependency JAR's should be packaged inside the lib while building the WAR

I am using **packaging excludes tag**, To excludes the local jars. But it excludes all the jars  in the packaged war file. I want to include **only the maven dependencies.**

```
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                            <warName>${war.name}</warName>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>config</directory>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                                    <directory>${maven.lib.dir}</directory>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>                                
                                </resource>                                                                             
                            </webResources>
                            <archive>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Built-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-Date>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                            <packagingExcludes>META-INF/*.xml</packagingExcludes>                           
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/*lib/</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

I can exclude few jars by specifying the names in the excludes tag. But i have too many jars to be explicitly written under the excludes tags

```
<packagingExcludes>
        WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-*.jar,
        %regex[WEB-INF/lib/log4j-(?!over-slf4j).*.jar]
      </packagingExcludes>
```

**I need some configuration, where in i can exclude the complete folder**.

Comment: Why not simply remove lib folder? Maven will add them for you when building, and for IDE resolving you should use WTP-M2E connector to M2E plugin in Eclipse, which add them to project lib.

Comment: I cannot remove the lib folder. Since i am dealing with a legacy project. Only once maven builds are stable, I will remove the lib folder.

Comment: Have you tried official doc: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html first example from the page

Comment: I can  exclude few jars by specifying  the names  in the excludes tag. But i have too many jars to be explicitly written under the excludes tags.

Comment: But the very first example on this page exclude all jars from WEB-INF/lib, that is: `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`. `*` is wildcard for substitution jar names.

Comment: yup. But that creates problem, since maven dependency are also excluded from the packaged war file.I want my war to contain only maven dependencies ,not locally available jars present in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 3):

I finally (after few edits) understand your problem. Unfortunately I think it would be extremely hard to do without something you would call a hack. This is hard because maven do not really support manually added jars. It's considered bad practice but we try do something about it. Here is what you might do:

1. Copy maven dependencies to some temp directory
2. Insert sub-directory into `WEB-INF/lib`
3. Remove every `*.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib`, but not from sub-directory.

Here are more detailed steps:

First add copy-dependencies to some temp directory (in my case it is maven-deps)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/maven-deps</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Take in mind that in `Eclipse IDE` you get error in line with opening `<execution>`, but from tool-tip menu you can solve it by installing `m2e` connector from market (This plugin is not covered by default life-cycle. That's why you need connector).

After that we need tell maven to put this directory into `war` under `WEB-INF/lib`. Do the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>

        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/maven-deps</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib/maven-deps</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will insert directory `maven-deps` as sub-directory into `WEB-INF/lib` and exclude every `*.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib` but **NOT** from `WEB-INF/lib/maven-deps`

That way you will get only maven managed dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib/maven-deps` and this according to spec should be visible from `war` class loader, because class loader should load all jars from `WEB-INF/lib` and it's sub-directories.

I know this is kind of hack but at the moment I can't think any better solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got a work around for this. I am renaming the lib folder to ant-libs and then excluding it from packaging. Once my war is created i am renaming ant-libs folder back to lib.

Answer (score 1):

I got a work around for this. I am renaming the lib folder to ant-libs and then excluding it from packaging. Once my war is created i am renaming ant-libs folder back to lib.

**Maven coderplus plugin:**

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>rename-file</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>rename</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <sourceFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</sourceFile>
                      <destinationFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/ant-libs</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>rename-file-back</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>rename</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <sourceFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/ant-libs</sourceFile>
                      <destinationFile>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
```

**Maven war plugin:**

```
                 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>${war.name}</warName>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>config</directory>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>                                    
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                            <directory>${maven.lib.dir}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            </resource> 
                        </webResources>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Built-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-Date>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/*ant-libs/</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `<scope>provided</scope>` for the dependency and it will not be packaged into war. See [more about maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism#Dependency_Scope)

If you need to exclude certain files from the WAR file, use [`packagingExcludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes). Files will not be included to the final war but still be present in `webappDirectory` (the directory where the webapp is built).

As stated in [Maven WAR Plugin reference](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html):

> **Including and Excluding Files From the WAR**
>
> It is possible to include or exclude certain **files** from the WAR file, by using the  and  configuration parameters. They each take a comma-separated list of Ant file set patterns. You can use wildcards such as ** to indicate multiple directories and * to indicate an optional part of a file or directory name.
>
> Here is an example where we exclude all JAR files from WEB-INF/lib:
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.6</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```

Comment: I don't want to exclude the maven dependencies from war. I want only local jars checked in WEB-INF/lib to be excluded.

Comment: If you use some jar in your project - this is the dependency. Don't check them in to WEB-INF/lib use maven repository for that. Or just put to different folder outside of src/main/webapp

Comment: I am dealing with legacy product. I cannot make any changes to existing structure or folders.I am just migrating to maven. once everything seems stable, i will remove the checked in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: `packagingExcludes` should do what you need. Just not be confused that excluded jars are still in `webappDirectory`. They are excluded from the final war.

Comment: Yup, packagingExcludes  excludes all the jars from the final War file generally referred to as **Skinny Wars**. But here my objective  is not  to exclude all the jars from final War file.  I Just want the maven dependencies mentioned in my pom. xml to be part of my war and checked in local jars in WEB-INF/lib folder to be excluded.

Comment: @Seeker, did you try `packagingExcludes`? I have tried, that works.

Comment: yes, packagingExcludes does work, but it excludes all the libraries  from the final WAR even the maven dependencies. I want maven dependencies to be packaged as part of WAR.

Comment: I got the different results. My build section is just:

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


As workaround you may exclude jars by pattern.

Comment: I have long list of  jars that are to be excluded. It will be difficult to explicitly mention all of them in pom itself. And excluding  the entire WEB-INF/lib folder does not solve my problem. Since it excludes both my local jars and maven dependencies.

Comment: Did you try maven-war-plugin v.2.6 ? It may work differently with other plugin version

Comment: Let me check with 2.6 version. Currently i am using version 2,4.

Comment: i am facing similar issue with 2..6 version of maven war plugin as well.